# Specifying alternate glyphs for potentially unrepresented unicode code point

Tags: web, unicode, utf-8

Unicode has a lot of fancy code points that can be used to do things like change the direction text is formatted, include inband protocol information and other things.

I want to find out if there is a way of specifying, as part of a unicode string, a 'fallback' glyph or set of glyphs where an uncommon unicode code point is unrepresented in the font being used to display the text?

Example: 
"æ<character to signify use following as alternate if previous character unavailable>ae<character to specify end of alternate>"

I've had a look through some of these code points at unicode.org and tried some different searches on SO without success. Some of the topics I've looked at:

Is there a way to programatically determine if a font file has a specific Unicode Glyph? (Windows/C#)
How to map code points to unicode characters depending on the font used? (Java)

Comment: The question is far too unclear, with many digressions, for a constructive answer. The title of the question and part of the body revolve around fallbacks, which are not a Unicode issue at all, but might be handled at other protocol levels. The tag “web” suggests that the question should be about something completely different, like fallback fonts on web pages.

Comment: Apologies, I'm aware it's a terrible, amorphous question and I'll correct it if I or anyone else manage to come up with a better way to phrase it - essentially I want to avoid �s appearing if possible for very rare characters, and provide an alternative where possible, while maintaining the semantic meaning of the original code point. Fallback fonts are not really a solution if the code point is rare enough that they don't contain it.

Comment: The symbol “�” U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER indicates *data error* (the data does not represent any character), not a font/glyph issue. It means that no code point has been identified. – You might get somewhere if you rewrite the question, describing what you have done and what has happened.

Comment: What you ask is decided by the text engine. Depending on the text engine and at what level you work you might force things your way or not. For instance if you are on Windows using Uniscribe directly, you can do that. If you are working at a higher level, you don't.